# Python: using regex and a loop to clean mulitiple text files

Tags: python, regex, file, text

I'm cleaning newspaper articles stored in separated text files.

In one of the cleaning stages, I want to remove all the text within one file that comes after the deliminator 'LOAD-DATE:'. I use a small piece of code that does the work when applied to just one string. See below.

```
line = 'A little bit of text. LOAD-DATE: And some redundant text'

import re
m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', line)
if m:
    line = m.group(1)
    line = re.sub('LOAD-DATE:', '', line)   
    print(line)
```

> A little bit of text.

However, when I translate the code to a loop to clean a whole bunch of seperate text files (which works fine in other stages of the script), than it produces gigantic, identical text files, which don't look at all like the original newspaper articles. See loop:

```
files = glob.glob("*.txt")

for f in files:
    with open(f, "r") as fin: 
        try:
            import re
            m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', fin)
            if m:
                data = m.group(1)
                data = re.sub('LOAD-DATE:', '', data)   
        except:
            pass

    with open(f, 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data)
```

Something clearly goes wrong in the loop, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Can you produce a sample output of the saved data?

Comment: lots of things going on here, but note that you don't ever actually read the open file: `m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', fin)` --> `m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', fin.read())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going line by line through the file. Something like

```
import re

files = glob.glob("*.txt")

for f in files:
    with open(f, "r") as fin:
        data = []

        for line in fin:
            m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', line)
            if m:
                line = m.group(1)
                line = re.sub('LOAD-DATE:', '', line)
            data.append(line)

    with open(f, 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, this completely did the job. I also managed to implement various other regular expression in this loop, which improved my data cleaning substantially.

Answer (score 0):

I made 10 txt files all containing the string:

```
 A little bit of text. LOAD-DATE: And some redundant text
```

I changed the `m` variable as patrick suggested to allow the file to be opened and read.

```
   m = re.match('(.*LOAD-DATE:)', fin.read())
```

But I also found that I had to include the `writelines` inside the if statement

```
        if m:
            data = m.group(1)
            data = re.sub('LOAD-DATE:', '', data)   
            with open(f, 'w') as fout:
                fout.writelines(data)
```

It changed them all no problem and very quickly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you John, I reckon this code should work, but for some reason I don't implement it well in the existing loop. However, the top solution works.